# shadow-cljs not resolving dependency

Tags: dependencies, clojurescript, shadow-cljs

Command from terminal: 
`npx shadow-cljs watch app`

build failure:  
`The required namespace "cljs-http.client" is not available, it was required by "learn/hello.cljs"`

How can I fix the above issue?

shadow-cljs.edn:

```
{:dependencies
 [[reagent "0.9.1"]
  [cljs-http "0.1.46"]]
 :source-paths
 ["src" "test"]
 :builds
 {:app {:target :browser
        :output-dir "resources/public/js"
        :asset-path "/js"
        :modules {:main {:entries [learn.hello]}}}}}
```

hello.cljs:

```
(ns learn.hello
  (:require [reagent.core :as r]
            [reagent.dom :as rdom]
            [clojure.string :as str]
            [cljs.core.async :refer [<!]]
            [cljs-http.client :as http])
  (:require-macros [cljs.core.async.macros :refer [go]]) )
```

Comment: Try running `shadow-cljs compile app` first. Your sample code above looks OK to me.

Comment: Tried `npx shadow-cljs compile app` as suggested. Unfortunately same error message.

Comment: Do you maybe have a running server instance from before you added the dependencies? Does it say "connected to server" when running the compile? If so you maybe just need to restart the old process?

Comment: @heller you are right. It was a running server instance. If you write it up as an answer, I can accept it. Would it be possible for the server to check if shadow-cljs.edn has changed? Thanks for your great work on shadow-cljs!